# Error in ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

I try to send ajax request in my SpringMVC project.

```
$.ajax({
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type : 'get',
    url : 'order/get/'+i,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {},
    success : function(result) {
        alert("Successfully!");
    },
    error : function(result, status, er) {
        alert("error: "+result+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }
});

@RequestMapping(value = "/order/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrder(
        @PathVariable("id") long id) {
    Order order = orderService.getOrderById(id);
    if (order == null) {
        new ResponseEntity<Order>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Order>(order, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But I always get error. 
In controller method return object of 'order', but ajax throws 'GET net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'. 
Why ?

Comment: share complete error message, client and server side

Comment: @sidgate all that is known of the error 'X-Requested-With'

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Order entity serialized to JSON with all the attributes, including those that marked as @ManyToOne. This serialization Json was excessive, and the response was very huge. The entity class Order, had to designate attributes such annotation @JsonIgnore. After this error is gone and the answer is processed normally.